# Add params in html5 video (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I'm a beginner in javascript and jQuery and would like to add a parameter to a video element with javascript.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#foo').append($('autoplay'));
});
</script>

<video id="foo" source type="video/mp4" src="foo.mp4">
```

I want the result to be:

```
<video id="foo" source type="video/mp4" src="foo.mp4" autoplay>
```

This didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change a property on an element you should always use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('#foo').prop('autoplay', true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/